# JQuery Get Label Value for Chosen Radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
 <label>
<input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="0" id="LargestMeeting_0" />
Less Than 5,000 sqft (<span id="lm1" class="detect lm1"></span>)</label>
 <br />
  <label>
<input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="5000" id="LargestMeeting_1" />
5,000 or more sqft (<span id="lm2" class="detect lm2"></span>)</label>
  <br />
  <label>
   <input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="10000" id="LargestMeeting_2" />
10,000 or more sqft (<span id="lm3" class="detect lm3"></span>)</label>
  <br />
<label>
<input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="20000" id="LargestMeeting_3" />
20,000 or more sqft (<span id="lm4" class="detect lm4"></span>)</label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="30000" id="LargestMeeting_4" />
   30,000 or more sqft (<span id="lm5" class="detect lm5"></span>)</label>
```

and I want to (from within a function) grab the value of the label for the checked radio box.  I thought it would look something like this:

```
var mylabel = $("label[for='input[name=LargestMeeting]:checked']").text();
alert(mylabel)
```

What am I missing?  It's coming out blank.

Comment: When you run that code, you get a blank alert window?

Comment: None of your `<label>` elements have a`for` attribute, which you're attempting to use as a selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. The issue is with the way you have the selectors nested. If you grab the checked `input` and select its parent, you can output the text you want easily.

See this example:

```js
function routesearch2() {
  var myLabel = $('input[name=LargestMeeting]:checked').parent().text();
  alert(myLabel);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
<input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="0" id="LargestMeeting_0" />
Less Than 5,000 sqft (<span id="lm1" class="detect lm1"></span>)</label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="5000" id="LargestMeeting_1" />
5,000 or more sqft (<span id="lm2" class="detect lm2"></span>)</label>
<br />
<label>
   <input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="10000" id="LargestMeeting_2" />
10,000 or more sqft (<span id="lm3" class="detect lm3"></span>)</label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="20000" id="LargestMeeting_3" />
20,000 or more sqft (<span id="lm4" class="detect lm4"></span>)</label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="30000" id="LargestMeeting_4" />
   30,000 or more sqft (<span id="lm5" class="detect lm5"></span>)</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$("input[name=LargestMeeting]:checked").parent().text()
```

and to clean up white spaces you can add

```
$.trim($("input[name=LargestMeeting]:checked").parent().text())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `input` tag is self closing, you won't get the text you want. You need to select the checked input first, then go up to parent, then get the content by `text()` and call `trim()` to trim the text.

```
var mylabel = $("label input[name=LargestMeeting]:checked").parent().text().trim();
```

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function() {
  var mylabel = $("label input[name=LargestMeeting]:checked").parent().text().trim();
  console.log(mylabel);
});


//place holder
function routesearch2() {};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="0" id="LargestMeeting_0" /> Less Than 5,000 sqft (<span id="lm1" class="detect lm1"></span>)</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="5000" id="LargestMeeting_1" /> 5,000 or more sqft (<span id="lm2" class="detect lm2"></span>)</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="10000" id="LargestMeeting_2" /> 10,000 or more sqft (<span id="lm3" class="detect lm3"></span>)</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="20000" id="LargestMeeting_3" /> 20,000 or more sqft (<span id="lm4" class="detect lm4"></span>)</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="radio" onchange="routesearch2()" name="LargestMeeting" value="30000" id="LargestMeeting_4" /> 30,000 or more sqft (<span id="lm5" class="detect lm5"></span>)</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Javascript`:

```
var meetings = document.getElementsByName('LargestMeeting');
for(var i = 0; i < meetings.length; i++){
    if(meetings[i].checked){
        selected_value = meetings[i].value;
    }
}
```